# Copy a specific range to from one sheet to the first empty row and specific column in another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use Google Sheets and I'm trying to use a script that copies certain ranges from a sheet (that reads CSV files) to a separate sheet's last available row, but to a certain column.
I also don't want to copy empty values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgGP3.png

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wog9C.png)

So I need to copy values only of a specific range from a sheet, like Sheet1!A5:D14, where it ignores empty values, to a different sheet's first empty row, but not the same column (so everything moves forward to column C-F).

I was able to use this, to copy things to a specific column:

```
function copyRange(e){
  var copyFromRange = 'Sheet1!B3:J10'; // no row for second cell reference
  var copyToRangeStart = 'Sheet2!B12';
  copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart);
}

function copyValuesOnly(copyFromRange, copyToRangeStart) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange(copyFromRange);
  source.copyTo(ss.getRange(copyToRangeStart), {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

However, this copies empty rows too, and can't find the first empty row in the other sheet.

I tried using code like this;

```
function moveValuesOnly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getRange("B10:AH13");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
  destSheet.appendRow(source.getValues()[0]);
}
```

This only copies a single row, and I can't copy it to a certain column on the other sheet, will always start in "A".

I'm not big on coding, if someone could help me here, that'd be amazing.

In short, the function I need has to;

- copy a selected range of values without formatting
- not copy empty rows
- paste to the first empty available row in a different sheet
- adjust which column it starts pasting the copied data to.

*EDIT:*

- keep previous data in sheet 2 (new data doesn't overwrite anything)
- function repeatable infinitely, the new data always gets added in the empty rows below in sheet 2.

Thanks to anyone who takes the time to help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyRange(){
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const srcrg = 'Sheet1!B3:J10'; 
  const torg = 'Sheet2!B12';
  const desrg=ss.getRange(torg);
  const row=desrg.getLastRow();
  const col=desrg.getColumn();
  const dessh=desrg.getSheet();
  const src=ss.getRange(srcrg).getValues();
  let cnt=0
  src.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(r.join("")!="") {
      dessh.getRange(row+1+cnt++,col,1,r.length).setValues([r]);
    }
  });
}
```

Source:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 21 | 14 | 11 | 6 | 9 | 3 | 11 | 9 | 2 |
| 29 | 29 | 21 | 19 | 14 | 4 | 24 | 11 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 11 | 25 | 2 | 9 | 2 | 1 | 11 | 5 | 29 |
| 3 | 3 | 24 | 18 | 28 | 6 | 6 | 20 | 19 | 23 |
| 4 | 16 | 4 | 17 | 25 | 14 | 8 | 22 | 4 | 15 |
| 26 | 15 | 7 | 25 | 7 | 2 | 10 | 26 | 10 | 19 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 4 | 18 | 6 | 5 | 18 | 27 | 2 | 27 | 5 | 0 |
| 15 | 5 | 26 | 22 | 13 | 18 | 6 | 27 | 28 | 24 |

Destination:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | 29 | 21 | 19 | 14 | 4 | 24 | 11 | 1 | 0 |
|  | 11 | 25 | 2 | 9 | 2 | 1 | 11 | 5 | 29 |
|  | 3 | 24 | 18 | 28 | 6 | 6 | 20 | 19 | 23 |
|  | 16 | 4 | 17 | 25 | 14 | 8 | 22 | 4 | 15 |
|  | 15 | 7 | 25 | 7 | 2 | 10 | 26 | 10 | 19 |
|  | 18 | 6 | 5 | 18 | 27 | 2 | 27 | 5 | 0 |
|  | 5 | 26 | 22 | 13 | 18 | 6 | 27 | 28 | 24 |

Comment: This is almost perfect, but what I'm looking for is to be able to run the function over and over, and it should insert the copies below the existing data each time.

Essentially, the target sheet should be the "database" and the original sheet is an ever changing "source table". I want to load the values from the source (sheet1) to the persistent sheet (sheet 2).

Comment: Well you're welcome to modify it to your hearts content.

Comment: Sadly, if I knew how to do that properly, I'd not have asked for help from the community here, but just did it from the get-go :(

Comment: If you want to learn then you will have to try.  If you don't wish  to try then you are not really part of the community.

Comment: I'm not a programmer, I don't know how to code, an I don't really want to learn. I came here for help, not for judgment from others.

If you don't want to help, don't, but I don't see why you need to be condescending here. I genuinely was just seeking help from people.

Comment: I'm not condescending this is a forum where programmers help programmers.  If your not a programmer then your not a member of the community.